# Clipping in vtk surface rendered output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, vtk

I had done surface rendering using vtk marching cubes and now I need to do clipping in that.

I searched and found how to do clipping in volume rendered output(i.e.; using ray casting method) .But I need to do clipping in surface rendered output.
so I created a vtkClipPolyData

```
plane->SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, pDoc->fBounds[4]);
plane->SetNormal(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);




clipper->SetInputConnection(//marchingcubes variable here//->GetOutputPort());
clipper->SetClipFunction(plane);
clipper->SetValue(.5);
clipper->Update();
polydata = clipper->GetOutput();//vtkPolyData//

mapper->SetInput(polydata);//vtkPolyDataMapper//
actor->SetMapper(mapper);//vtkActor//
```

And I am getting the clipped output.but the problem is I need to create a slider bar and as the slider is dragged the clipping should appear in axial view back and forth .Is my question clear? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a [vtkSliderWidget](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkSliderRepresentation.html). There's an example of how to use it [here](https://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/Widgets/Cxx/Slider.cxx). On its callback, you can set the clipping plane's position.

Another option: You could use a [vtkImplicitPlaneWidget2](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImplicitPlaneWidget2.html) (note: the 2 there is because there's a new and an old version - use the '2' versions whenever possible).

Comment: i already created slider bar using CScrollBar class.now i need to use that slider to work with vtk

Comment: Then, all you need to do is, on the slider's value changed event, set your plane's origin, call Update on the polydata, set a new input to the mapper and call Render.